# Msbuild task to find specific filetype

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

How can we find a specific file type under a path? I have checked [MSBuild Task Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) but couldn't figure out.

Looking for something as:

```
<FindUnderPath Path="$(OutDir)"  Files="*.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="InPath" ItemName="AllTxtFiles"/>
</FindUnderPath>
```

But it fails sayings "MSB3541: Files has invalid value "*.txt""

P.S. I am a rookie at msbuild tasks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ItemGroup to specify such files and reference the ItemGroup in the Files parameter. Something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include="*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
<FindUnderPath Path="$(OutDir)" Files="@(MyFiles)">
    <Output TaskParameter="InPath" ItemName="AllTxtFiles" />         
</FindUnderPath>
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164293(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you just need list of all txt files in certain folder you can get it as simple as

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AllTxtFiles Include="$(PathToFolder)\**\*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Double stars (**) means that folder should be searched recursively for file pattern